# Vote counts with exactly three digits don't display properly on the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When there is a vote count above 100 but below 1000, the Stack Exchange Android app displays it on two lines:

[image: Screenshot of 837 votes]

<sup>V. 0.1.55 on Nexus 7 (2012) on Android 4.3</sup>

Comment: Looks fine to me....on  a question with over 1,000 upvotes.

Comment: Hmm.  I misspoke.  I tested it earlier with my phone and it looked fine.  I tested it with my Nexus 7 and I'm seeing what you're seeing now.

Comment: It looks like this bug is back: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242870/votes-with-3-numbers-or-more-are-on-different-lines

Answer (score 3):

Great catch, that was my bad. I had fixed the site question list to automatically resize text rather than use hardcoded values which didn't scale up to tablets but I forgot to do the same fix on the actual question detail side. This will go out in the 0.1.56 update coming out later tonight.

Fixed screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I noticed this still doesn't work in some answers. Check the big secret hats post, for example.