# Some three-digit (incl. minus sign) vote count still doesn't display properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

> **Related:**
>   [Vote counts with exactly three digits don't display properly on the Stack Exchange Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203191/vote-counts-with-exactly-three-digits-dont-display-properly-on-the-stack-exchan)

As the title says...

[image: Worse Than Failure]

The Android app version is 0.1.58.

Here is my experimental results:

- <s>Vote counts >= 200 that I've tried seems to be fine</s>
- Vote count == 241 has problem, 242 doesn't
- Vote counts which matches `/^1[012345689][0-9]$/` seems to be having problem (may be overgeneralized)
- Vote count == -36 definitely has problem

Note that this is not a tablet, but a 4-inch mdpi phone, of 480x854px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report.

This has been fixed for version 0.1.60 coming out later tonight, I checked it against your very helpful use cases and some other ones I thought of after I saw what the root cause was.

Comment: There's still a small [edge case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242104/the-vote-counter-bugs-when-reaching-100-up-votes-in-android).