# App force close when closing question before it's loaded

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When you load a question with a code block, and use the back button (home button does not cause this issue) before the question has loaded, the app will force close. I'd imagine it has to do with the WebView rendering the code blocks?

<sup>using v0.1.59</sup>

Comment: Also sorry to the devs for all the automated crash reports triggered by me trying to diagnose this

Comment: No worries, they bundle up automatically :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my bad, I created this bug while doing my fix for [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203783/some-three-digit-incl-minus-sign-vote-count-still-doesnt-display-properly) which included running some logic on the UI thread after a question was loaded.

<s>It's fixed in version 0.1.60 coming out later tonight.</s>

Okay, fixed (again) but for real this time, in version 0.1.61 coming out later tonight.

I thought this was a bug with the loading of a question not being aware that the view was killed and trying to still show the data it just loaded, but what it ended up being was a less likely scenario of a race condition when the view is killed between "do this calculation on the UI thread" and the UI thread running. Fixed.

Comment: Hate to say it, I'm still able to reproduce this in v0.1.60. Its the exact same stack trace as laalto posted.

Comment: Reproduced on my end too. Status changed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't reproduce on 0.1.58 but easily reproduced on 0.1.59. Here's the stacktrace, nothing to do with `WebView`:

```
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531): java.lang.NullPointerException: [v0.1.59] 
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.QuestionFragment$4.run(QuestionFragment.java:171)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-03 09:36:47.693: E/AndroidRuntime(10531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```