# The vote counter bugs when reaching 100 up-votes in Android

Tags: bug, android-app

As you can see in the image below, when I up-voted an answer that had 99 votes, the typeface didn't shrink in order to show a one-lined 100 number.

I'm using Android 4.4.4 on a Nexus 7 (2012).

[image]

Comment: @nicael didn't notice. Thanks.

Comment: This will most likely look OK once you refresh the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought the same, but as of now, it's still displayed in this weird wrapped way.

Comment: This is fixed in the next update.