# First number of vote count is cut off when viewing user profile in Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Two issues here: I checked but didn't find a post yet on the first one. The second I know has existing posts but I believe all are marked status-complete so figured I'd bring it up just in case.

**Issue 1:**

When viewing a user's profile who has a post with a large number of votes, the first number is being cut off. In the screenshot below, you can see that the '4' is being cut off of '4536'. The screenshot is viewing in vertical orientation but it is cut off when I switch it to horizontal as well. I'm not sure if on a wider screen, possibly on a tablet, it will even be an issue. I'm on a 4.3 inch, 540x960px display.

Here is a quick [link to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and a [link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/738262) I've referenced.

[image: User profile picture]

**Issue 2:**

Like I said, I know there are already posts regarding the vote count wrapping issue (one of which I posted. I didn't see one already existed so it was a duplicate). The reason I'm even mentioning it again is when I viewed that answer (from the issue above), the vote count is wrapped (as seen in the screenshot below). Each of the posts I've found regarding the vote count wrapping issue are marked status-complete and I don't see one currently open regarding the issue. Vertical and horizontal view is same wrap result on my phone. Here are some links to those existing posts:

- [Some three-digit (incl. minus sign) vote count still doesn't display properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203783/some-three-digit-incl-minus-sign-vote-count-still-doesnt-display-properly)
- [Vote counts with exactly three digits don't display properly on the Stack Exchange Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203191/vote-counts-with-exactly-three-digits-dont-display-properly-on-the-stack-exchan)
- (the one I posted which is a duplicate) [Vote Count Wrapping Issue on Some Questions in Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203905/vote-count-wrapping-issue-on-some-questions-in-android-app)

[image: Vote count wrapping issue]

I'm on version 0.1.79

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Jon Skeet always breaks my test cases... both of these bugs have been fixed for version 0.1.80 coming out around midnight UTC, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quick fix! Figured you'd enjoy an easy one on NYE :) As always, I'll mark it answered soon as I get the update. Thanks!