# Votes with 3 numbers or more are on different lines on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, vote-count

In the Android app, votes with 3 numbers (or more, maybe) are showed on different lines.

[image: 251 score, or 25 up & 1 down!?]

We need to make the font smaller, or the sidebar containing the votes bigger, or some clever developer thing.

Might be worth mentioning this is on a tablet.

Comment: This _was_ fixed. Dunno what happened.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce looks like that problem is back-status not completed

Comment: The root cause for this has been fixed and is pending an update, it also breaks on 4-character vote counts right now.